# Using a Button to Calculate and Populate a field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a simple part number database with ruby on rails and have got the basic functionality working nicely.  Now I have a problem where I am so out of my depth I don't even know what to search for to find examples and solutions.

I have a view "new.html.erb" that is a form to create new part numbers, but what I would like to have is a button that would search my *part* model for the highest existing part number (e.g. 100000) and put the next sequential part number (e.g. 100001) in the :number field on my form.

There is a bit more functionality involving part number ranges, but the main problem is I am not sure how to structure this in an MVC environment.

A tutorial link or solution link would be great.

Thanks to all, I have had so much help solving other problems searching this forum.

Here is the view's code:

```
<h1>Create New Part</h1>

<%= form_for :part, url: parts_path do |f| %>

<!-- #This is the alert if there are errors -->
<% if @part.errors.any? %>

    <%@part.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= msg %></div>
    <% end %>

<% end %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field(:number, {:class => 'form-control'})%>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field(:description, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :inventorycode %><br>
    <%= f.text_field(:inventorycode, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.radio_button :category, 'wo', :checked => true %> 
    <%= f.label :category_wo, 'Work Order Part' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :category, 'standard' %>
    <%= f.label :category_standard, 'Standard Part' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :category, 'purchased' %>
    <%= f.label :category_purchased, 'Purchased Part' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :category, 'template' %>
    <%= f.label :category_template, 'Template Part' %>
</p>


<p>
    <%= f.radio_button :lifecycle, 'current', :checked => true %> 
    <%= f.label :lifecycle_current, 'Current Part' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :lifecycle, 'obsolete' %>
    <%= f.label :lifecycle_obsolete, 'Obsolete Part' %>
</p>

<P>
    <%= f.check_box :hasdrawing %>
    <%= f.label :hasdrawing, "Part has drawing" %>
</P>

<p>
    <%= f.submit({:class => 'btn btn-primary'}) %>

</p>

<% end -%>
```

Comment: Have you considered if more that one user accessing the page? and is there a reason you don't want to set then number once the part is saved (via auto increment)

Comment: I don't *think* there will be more than one user at a time, so I think I can mitigate that problem.  I do need to allow for either going with the next number in sequence or entering a new part number manually.  There will be "holes" in the series of part numbers, that people will want to fill.

Answer (score 0):

First, take in consideration the comments of @dezull, because there are good points. But if you keep looking to do this having that in mind, you can do this on the controller, for example

```
def new
  @part = Part.new(part_params)
  @part.number = Part.maximum("number")+1
end
```

and this will set the number of the part that you are creating to the highest + 1

Comment: As mentioned above, I need to allow for either the next sequential number or a user input number.  Along this line, would there be a way of just checking the number field and if it is empty, using what you suggest?

Comment: The number would be on the form on the create, after the form is rendered, then the user can change it, and if there is an error on the create, there would be the value that were submitted, no matter if what value was, just try it

Comment: OK, I tried it and I think I know what you mean now.  I am getting the number field populating when I open the Create New Part form.  (I have some errors, but I think I can clean that up myself)  The problem is that there are different ranges of part numbers that correspond with the :category radio buttons,  so for 'standard' category parts, the part numbers will be between 300000-599999, for 'purchased' category parts, the part numbers will be between 600000-899999, etc.  As such I would need to populate the number field after a category is selected.